# How to get Slider value in Playgrounds?

Tags: swift, slider

I'm trying to update a label with the value of a slider. Ive got the slider on screen but I can seem to get the values when it's changed.

```
//This in viewDidLoad 

slider.minimumValue = 0
slider.maximumValue = 100
slider.addTarget(self, action: Selector("sliderUpdate"), for: .allEditingEvents)
view.addSubview(slider)

@objc func sliderUpdate(sender: UISlider) {
    lbl2.text = String(Int(sender.value))
}
```

Comment: FYI - your issue is not specific to a Swift playground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `#selector(sliderUpdate)` and the event is `.valueChanged`.

```
slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderUpdate), for: .valueChanged)
```